# Converting excel date serial to date in postgres

Tags: excel, postgresql, date

So I've got a large mass of excel files that aren't formatted properly and because of this their dates aren't being read in as dates, but as the date serial they use (i think the number of days since 1900-1-1?). Ex: 41917.0054050926 is really 10/5/2014  12:07:47 AM.

All I need is the actual date, not the time. I know I can get the year by doing 41917/365.25, rounding and adding this to 1900, but i'm not sure how to get the day and the month. Is there anything built into postgres to handle this? If not, does anyone know an arithmetic way of finding the day and year?

Thanks!

Comment: @pnutsyea, the only issue is theres a ton of files that were created by an external source. Doing 41917.0054050926 % 365.25 was able to give me the day of the year, gonna see if theres a way to leverage that in postgres

Answer (score 6):

I just had this issue and wrote a plpgsql function to handle it. Note that it will work on whole numbers only meaning it will only do dates, not date and time. Someone else can feel free to expand it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION To_Timestamp_From_Excel (ExcelDate integer)
RETURNS timestamp without time zone AS $$
BEGIN
   IF ExcelDate > 59 THEN
    ExcelDate = ExcelDate - 1;
   END IF;
   RETURN date '1899-12-31' + ExcelDate;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You would need to call it like this if you have date and time encoded or if your field type is text:

```
UPDATE myTable set MyDateField = to_Timestamp_From_Excel(MyDateField::integer)
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering about the 59, it is because Excel "thought" there was a leap year in 1900, but it turns out, leap years are every 4 years, except for the centurial years that are not divisible by 4 (1500,1700,1800,1900,2100). 
https://science.howstuffworks.com/science-vs-myth/everyday-myths/question50.htm
So basically, In Excel dates (represented by integers), there was a February 29, 1900 but in reality that date never existed!  (Who knew??)

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=ROUND(A1,0)+1
```

and format **B1** as *mm/dd/yyyy*

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit messy and not 100% accurate, but I can do this in a custom PG procedure:

41917.0054050926/365.25 gets the year

41917.0054050926%365.25 gets the day of the year

I can then add the day of the year as an interval to the last day of the previous year.

Answer (score 0):

I use an instruction like that:
select timestamp '1899/12/30' + interval '43404 day 43200'
to obtain '2018/10/30 12:00:00'
In Excel this date is 43404.5, then i have integer part before "day" inside interval, and fraction multiplied by 86400 (seconds per day).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cdate(rhs anyelement) RETURNS timestamp without time zone AS
$BODY$
DECLARE retval timestamp without time zone;
BEGIN
IF pg_typeof($1)=ANY ('{int2,int,int8,real,float8,numeric}'::regtype[]) THEN
    retval:=DATE_TRUNC('second',DATE('1899-12-30')+$1*INTERVAL '1 day');
ELSE
    IF pg_typeof($1)=ANY ('{timestamp,date}'::regtype[]) THEN
        retval:=$1::timestamp without time zone;
    END IF;
END IF;
RETURN retval;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without creating the function, you can try:

Postgresql convert sql date to excel serialized date:

```
date_part('day', here_your_date - '1900-01-01'::date)+2 AS excel_serialized_date
```

Excel serialized to Postgresql date:

```
-- for e.g.: excel_serialized_date = 44492
(to_date('1900-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + excel_serialized_date::integer)-2 as exceldate_to_postgresqldate,
/* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/wrongly-assumes-1900-is-leap-year
 therefore -2 is needed */
```

In the Excel quick verification by the formula:

```
=Text(44492,"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Answer (score 0):

Handles date&time:

```
create or replace function parse_excel_timestamp("timestamp" numeric) returns timestamp as $$
    begin
        if (timestamp = 0) then
            return null;
        end if;
        return timestamp '1899-12-30' + make_interval(days => floor(timestamp)::int, secs => round((timestamp % 1) * 3600 * 24));
    end
$$ language plpgsql immutable;
```